# "And am happy" is correct or not in this context?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs

I work as a police and am happy with it.

or

I work as a police, and I am happy with it.

or

both are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, as far as the "I" goes, but one does not say "I work as a police". Rather it should be

> - I work as a policeman.
> - I work as a policewoman.
> - I work as a police officer.

The sentence:

> I work as a police officer and am happy with it.

has elided the second "I", which is implied. This is fine.

Comment: Or: I work in the police department, or I word in the police force.